# Selenium and DevTools give different result

Tags: selenium-webdriver, iframe, devtools

I try to track any imgs' resize in a page, so I run a script in all frames (main frame and iframe).

```
// This is the script
if(typeof(resize_log) === 'undefined')
    resize_log = [];
                
const resizeOb= new ResizeObserver(entries => {
    for(const entry of entries) {
        var j = {};
        j.tag = "e8fa9d";
        j.src = entry.target.src;
        j.width = entry.target.width;
        j.height = entry.target.height;
        
        resize_log.push(j);
    }
});

elements = document.getElementsByTagName("img")
for(let i=0; i<elements.length; i++)
    resizeOb.observe(elements[i])
```

So as you can see, this script will write all logs into global variable *resize_logs*.

And when I read *resize_logs* in DevTools, it appears that *resize_logs.length* is 200+, but when I run a code in Selenium, it turns to 165.

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
resize_log = driver.execute_script('return window.resize_log')
```

[Selenium's result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2GWu.png)
[DevTools' result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZytb.png)

So why? Can this attribute to frame and iframe?

Comment: probably a timing issue... you're running async code there.